# NGINX-RTMP Issue

Tags: nginx, rtmp, live-streaming

I have configured NGINX-RTMP server and I can play live streaming on VLC Media Player.
But when I am trying to play it on website then it does not play.
Here is my RTMP configuration code of nginx.conf file.

```
rtmp {
    server {
            listen 1935;
            chunk_size 4096;

            application live {
                    live on;
                    record off;
            }
    }
}
```

I tried to play it via clappr player
Here is the code

```
var player = new Clappr.Player({
    source: "rtmp://192.168.4.136:1935/live/test",
    parentId: "#player",
    plugins: {'playback': [RTMP]},
    rtmpConfig: {
        swfPath: 'dist/assets/RTMP.swf',
        scaling:'stretch',
        playbackType: 'live',
        bufferTime: 1,
        startLevel: 0,
        switchRules: {
            "SufficientBandwidthRule": {
                "bandwidthSafetyMultiple": 1.15,
                "minDroppedFps": 2
            },
            "InsufficientBufferRule": {
                "minBufferLength": 2
            },
            "DroppedFramesRule": {
                "downSwitchByOne": 10,
                "downSwitchByTwo": 20,
                "downSwitchToZero": 24
            },
            "InsufficientBandwidthRule": {
                "bitrateMultiplier": 1.15
            }
        }
    },
});
```

I have the following error
[image]
Please help me to solve it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First thing (When u have a domain, OpenSSL won't work u will have to use CertBot.)
According to this, i didnt use the Clapp player i used one from the internet that worked.

Change what u want on the rtmp i've put here so doesn't do as many things EXCEPT

> NOT DELETE

```
 hls on;
 hls_path /nginx/hls;
 hls_fragment 3;
 hls_playlist_length 60;
 # disable consuming the stream from nginx as rtmp
 deny play all;
```

> WHAT TO DO ON YOUR LINUX CONSOLE

```
sudo mkdir /nginx
sudo mkdir /nginx/hls
```

In the rtmp try this:

```
rtmp {
server {
    listen 1935; # Listen on standard RTMP port
    chunk_size 4000;

    application live {
        live on;
        # Turn on HLS
        hls on;
        hls_path /nginx/hls;
        record all;
        record_path /videos;
        hls_fragment 3;
        hls_playlist_length 60;
        # disable consuming the stream from nginx as rtmp
        deny play all;
    }
}
}
```

And on the website at that time I did it like this:

> On the website change the ip and the port

```
   <head>
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.6.6/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.6.6/video.js"></script>
<title>Stream PAGE</title>
<!-- This style is clearly not needed but yolo  -->
<style>
  body {
width: 35em;
margin: 0 auto;
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
 }
</style>
</head>   
<body>
<h1>What you want</h1>
<video id="player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="800" height="440"  controls preload="none">
<source src="http://192.168.205.1:9000/1234.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL" />
</video>
 <script>
 var player = videojs('#player')
  </script>
```

[You should be able after completing the web something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVjBk.png)

In case this doesn't help you this video saved me countless hours of work when redoing it all again: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-9kVF6bWr4&t